# How to set and display images with original size (not cropped) in Betheme Masonry Blog Style?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, masonry

I am using Betheme for my wordpress website and i am using its Masonry Blog Style(which is mandatory) for blog posts. 
The images(featured images) of the content displayed on the blog page are of random sizes as defined in the monsory blog style.

But i want that the all the images which are being displayed on the blog page should be in their full size.

Betheme Monsory  Blog style for reference
https://themes.muffingroup.com/be/theme/blog/masonry-blog-style/?mfn-s

I have applied custom CSS to change the sizes of the wrappers/divs in which the images are being displayed.

Wrapper used in theme for blog style.

```
<html>
<div class="image_frame post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid images_only">
   <div class="image_wrapper">
      <a href="http://*******.com/2019/05/15/123/">
         <div class="mask"></div>
         <img width="960" height="750" src="http://*******.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/z1s969obmsu11-960x750.jpg" class="scale-with-grid wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://*******.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/z1s969obmsu11-960x750.jpg 960w, http://*******.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/z1s969obmsu11-1280x1000.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px">
      </a>
      <div class="image_links double"><a href="http://*******.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/z1s969obmsu11-429x1024.jpg" class="zoom" rel="prettyphoto">
         <i class="icon-search"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="http://*******.com/2019/05/15/123/" class="link">
         <i class="icon-link"></i>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</html>
```

I have looked for the options in theme options but i couldn't find any option that will help me to solve the problem. Although the problem is minor one but it matters.

Comment: Probably a dumb suggestion, but have you tried setting your `img` height and width to `auto`?

Comment: @Shahroze Ali Remove inline styling and give the same width, height to all images.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett bro already tried that.

Comment: @MehrajKhan i can't. It's something already defined in theme. Masonry style define image sizes by itself depending on the space left on the page.
And i don't know from where to remove the inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has an image size called 'full', which will return the originally uploaded image.

Right now your theme shows the resized version of the uploaded image. It is **z1s969obmsu11-960x750.jpg**. If you use the 'full' image size, it will be **z1s969obmsu11.jpg**

If it's a CSS issue, use your browser's developer tool to check if the theme styles are overruling your custom styles. If so, improve the specificity of the CSS selector, or as a very very last solution, use !important.